Linkedin error code :- INVALID_CONTENT_OWNERSHIP, status code:-400
Hi I am trying to post image and content using linkedin api but am getting the following error in my code.
This is my code in python django:-
def post_content(access_token, user_id, content, image_path):
    try:
        POST_URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts'
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "LinkedIn-Version": "202402",
            "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"
        }
      
        # Initialize image upload
        initialize_upload_request = {
            "initializeUploadRequest": {
                "owner": f"urn:li:person:{user_id}"
            }
        }
        print("upload Payload:")
        print(json.dumps(initialize_upload_request, indent=4))
        initialize_upload_response = requests.post(
        "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images?action=initializeUpload",
        json=initialize_upload_request,
        headers=headers  # Pass the headers here
        )
        initialize_upload_data = initialize_upload_response.json()
        upload_url = initialize_upload_data['value']['uploadUrl']
        image_urn = initialize_upload_data['value']['image']
        
        # Upload image
        with open(image_path, 'rb') as file:
            response = requests.put(upload_url, data=file)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception if upload fails
        
        # Post content
        request_data = {
            "author": f"urn:li:person:{user_id}",
            "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
            "specificContent": {
                "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                    "shareCommentary": {
                        "text": content
                    },
                    "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE",
                    "media": [
                        {
                            "status": "READY",
                            "media": image_urn
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "visibility": {
                "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
            }
        }
        
        print("Request Payload:")
        print(json.dumps(request_data, indent=4))
      
        post_response = requests.post(POST_URL, json=request_data, headers=headers)
        print("ecec",post_response.json())
        if post_response.ok:
            print("Content posted successfully.")
            return {'success': True}
        else:
            error_message = post_response.text
            print(f"Failed to post content: {error_message}")
            return {'success': False, 'error': error_message}
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error posting content: {str(e)}")
        return {'success': False, 'error': str(e)}


This is the error when I try to post my content:-
Failed to post content: {"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","message":"com.linkedin.content.common.exception.BadRequestResponseException: One or more of the contents is not owned by the author. All contents must be owned by the author","errorDetails":{"inputErrors":[{"description":"Content(s) you provided must be owned by post author","input":{},"code":"INVALID_CONTENT_OWNERSHIP"}]},"status":400}
I cannot find this error code anywhere in the documentation and upon seeing both the upload and request payload the owner and author are the same. I saw one other post where a person had this error but there were no solutions.

I found the error it was because I was using ugc post and the old json request data using the latest one allowed me to post.
